# how to determine a priori probability distribution of sigama2 in montecarlo simulation?

Tags: bayesian, prior, posterior, sas, inverse-gamma-distribution

1、the monte carlo simulation code in SAS：
Example1:
https://support.sas.com/rnd/app/stat/examples/BayesStd/new_example/index.html

```
proc mcmc data=class outpost=classout nmc=10000 thin=2 seed=246810;
   parms beta0 0 beta1 0;
   parms sigma2 1;
   prior beta0 beta1 ~ normal(mean = 0, var = 1e6);
   prior sigma2 ~ igamma(shape = 3/10, scale = 10/3);
   mu = beta0 + beta1*height;
   model weight ~ n(mu, var = sigma2);
run;
```

What does the "parm sigma2 1"mean? 
Does it mean the sigma2's parameter begins from 1 in the simulation 
and why it begins from 1 but not 0.1、0.011、0.0001 or others?

Just like Example2 below:
https://www.phusewiki.org/docs/Conference%202017%20AS%20Papers/AS03.pdf

the variable "a_Sex" begins from 0.1 and the sigma2 begins from 0.0011.
So how to determine the variable's initial value?

```
proc mcmc data=Orthodont_tr outpost=outpost nbi=5000 nmc=25000 thin=15 plots=ALL; 
array mean[4]; 
array a_age[3]      a_age10 a_age12 a_age14; 
array a_sex_age[3]  a_sex_age10  a_sex_age12  a_sex_age14; 
array dist[4]       dist1 dist2 dist3 dist4; 
parms intercept 0.1 
      a_Sex 0.1 
      a_age: 0 
      a_sex_age: 0; 
parms S2 0.0011; 
parms Rho; 

prior intercept   ~ normal(0,var=1e6); 
prior a_Sex       ~ normal(0,var=1e6); 
prior a_age:      ~ normal(0,var=1e6); 
prior  a_sex_age: ~ normal(0,var=1e6); 
prior S2          ~ igamma(shape=0.01, scale=0.01); 
prior Rho         ~ uniform(-1,1); 

mean[1] = intercept + a_Sex * (Sex=1)                            ;/*time = 8*/ 
mean[2] = intercept + a_Sex * (Sex=1)+ a_age10 +  a_sex_age10 * (Sex=1);/*time = 10*/ 
mean[3] = intercept + a_Sex * (Sex=1)+ a_age12 +  a_sex_age12 * (Sex=1);/*time = 12*/ 
mean[4] = intercept + a_Sex * (Sex=1)+ a_age14 +  a_sex_age14 * (Sex=1);/*time = 14*/ 

model dist ~ mvnar(mean, var=S2, rho=Rho); 

run;
```

2、Why the sigma2's prior distribution in the 1st example is like this:

```
prior sigma2 ~ igamma(shape = 3/10, scale = 10/3)
```

But in the 2rd example:

```
prior S2 ~ igamma(shape=0.01, scale=0.01)
```

Why are they different? 
How to determine the sigma2's priori distribution and why the sigma2 has an igamma distribution?

---

@merv
Do you mean I need to use this formula below to calculate the igamma distribution's "shape(α)" and "scale(1/β)"?

But obviously it is impossible to get the "α=0.01" in Example2 through the "α+n/2"……
[image]

Comment: Please don't post image of your code, paste it and use code formatting instead.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar I have pasted all of the code in the Example1 and two key codes  about the question in the Example 2.

Comment: PhUse 2017 are coded images - equally, you may be better off at math.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar Ok,thanks. I have updated it.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `parms` values? In MCMC sampling for most models, it shouldn't matter where you initialize - as long as it eventually samples from the typical set, it should be good. If it is sensitive to these init values, then that could indicate a problem, or at least a need to discard a larger burn-in set (though the current `nbi=5000` is likely sufficient).

Comment: @merv OK，thanks. It means the initial value doesn't matter but what is the typical set(I think the normal distribution covers all real numbers?)? And do you know  why the sigma2 has an igamma distribution and how to  determine its distribution parameters?

Comment: @tumidou The typical set is the region where "most" of the posterior probability mass lies (a good intro to MCMC is [Michael Betacourt's lecture on *Scalable Bayesian Inference*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUSZboSq1zg)). For a linear regression, one models error as Normal, and when one doesn't know the mean or variance of this distribution, then the Normal-Inverse Gamma distribution is the conjugate prior (i.e., matches the posterior distribution). It's a bit technical, but a good summary is [the Wikipedia Conjugate Prior entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior).

Comment: @merv Thank you so much! I think I understand something. But how do we get the igamma's parameters (like in Example 2,shape=0.01 and scale=0.01)?